# Return unique list ordered by repeated/duplicated item count

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, distinct

What would be the most efficient path to the result I'm looking for? I'm using ASP.NET 4.5 and C#.

Let say I have the following `int` list:

`5,7,2,7,8,5,8,0,2,9,8,8,7`

I want to remove duplicates from the list and order it by the number of appearances of each item. I know I can use LINQ's `Distinct()` to make the items unique, but how can I also make it order by the number of appearances? This is the desired result for the example above:

`8,7,5,2,0,9`

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess that the person who downvoted your question was for the lack of efforts on your side.

Comment: I had plenty of efforts, I didn't think it was necessary to show my ridiculous loops to figure out the ordering as I knew it was wrong.

Comment: It is always necessary to show your efforts when asking a question. There's no such thing as *ridiculous efforts*. There are efforts. Everybody is learning and if someone tells you that your efforts are ridiculous you could tell him that he is ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ordered = list
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Marked your's as answer as it was the first answer. Since I'm working with List object, there should be a ".ToList()" on the end. Other than that, both your's and Darin's work great!

Answer (score 4):

You could group the items and then order them by the count in each group:

```
var items = new[] { 5, 7, 2, 7, 8, 5, 8, 0, 2, 9, 8, 8, 7 };
var result = items
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
    .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: why is that final Distinct needed?

Comment: It isn't needed. The GroupBy already gets rid of duplicate entries.

Comment: Correct, it is not needed at all. It was a bad copy-paste on my side. Thanks for pointing this out.